# Getting virtual key code by pressing a key in C++

Tags: c++

I want to make a program that shows the virtual key code of the key I press on keyboard. I am using `VkKeyScan(WCHAR)`. Below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    WCHAR wc = '0';

    while (1) {

        wc = getch();

        if (wc != '0') {
            system("cls");
            std::cout << std::hex << "\nKey Code: 0x" << VkKeyScan(wc);
            wc = '0';
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD0)) {
            system("cls");
            std::cout << "Exit...\n";
            Sleep(500);
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it does not work for keys like Shift, Ctrl, Alt, Insert ....., and it cannot differentiate between numeric keys and the numeric keypad. And I'm not working with any windows I'm on console application. Is it possible to get the virtual key code by a key press in C++ console application without using proper Win32 Desktop application?

Comment: "_The problem is that it does not work for keys like Shift, Ctrl, Alt_" From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-vkkeyscana): "_If the function succeeds, the low-order byte of the return value contains the virtual-key code and the high-order byte contains the shift state_"

Comment: You cannot start with `getch()`. This function returns a character, not a key. The information about keys that were pressed is lost. I don't think you can get keys in a console application (or maybe ReadConsoleInput can work, but I'm not sure about that).